# How to notify content-resolver after data changed in database?

Tags: android, sms, background-process

I've created one application that is inserting messages programmatically. In that application running successfully.

It'll inserted the message whatever given in record. After, you'll not able to see your inserted message in your messages where device or emulator. Check out that.

I don't know why this is happening. You'll able to see your message when, you stopped the messaging in your task manager. After, you can see your inserted message.

What am missing in that code.

Any help appreciated?  Best Regards - SPK

The code

Activity:

```
public class SMS extends Activity 
{
    Button btnSendSMS;
    EditText txtPhoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        
        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        final insert i = new insert(this);
        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                i.method_inser();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

Class insert:

```
public class insert
{
    Context ctx,context;
    ContentResolver cr;

    public insert(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        cr = context.getContentResolver();
    }
    public void method_inser()
    {
        Uri smsuri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
        ContentValues iv = new ContentValues();
        String[] final_result = {"1","1","15555215556","3","1320753694842","0","1","-1","1","0","null","Gingerbread","null","0","0","1"};
        iv.put("_id", final_result[0]);
        iv.put("thread_id", final_result[1]);
        iv.put("address", final_result[2]);
        iv.put("person", final_result[3]);
        iv.put("date", final_result[4]);
        iv.put("protocol", final_result[5]);
        iv.put("read", final_result[6]);
        iv.put("status", final_result[7]);
        iv.put("type", final_result[8]);
        iv.put("reply_path_present", final_result[9]);
        iv.put("subject", final_result[10]);
        iv.put("body", final_result[11]);
        iv.put("service_center", final_result[12]);
        iv.put("locked", final_result[13]);
        iv.put("error_code", final_result[14]);
        iv.put("seen", final_result[15]);
        cr.insert(smsuri, iv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is very hard to read and I don't think I really got your problem. Maybe somehow you are using MessageQueues and the messages are consumed by the background core application? Please add some relevant code and rewrite your question, because I don't really understand it.

Comment: I edited the question and added the code you provided, so maybe someone can help (unfortunately I can't). I get the feeling that some code is missing (there is nothing background-service related) - And I still don't really get your question. But maybe someone else can help.

Comment: @SPK Where the things releted to service.

Comment: @Sam_k : Which service do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_id` and `thread_id` are `primary key` and you are trying to insert fix value all the time so it will work only once

Also remove two fields `error_code` and `seen` because `there are no any column in a sms table`

Also you have to add following permissions in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS">
```

After inserting new message in inbox you have to notify changed using content resolver

Use this code to notify change

```
Uri uri = cr.insert(smsuri, iv);
cr.notifyChange(uri, null);
```